# Kleene Star Undecidability

Tags: computer-science, complexity-theory, computation-theory, turing-machines

I know that if L is decidable, we can prove that L* is also decidable by constructing  a Turing machine  but 
I am having trouble solving this: 
If  L is undecidable , then L* is also undecidable.
Is this sentence true or false ?

Comment: It's probably better to ask this on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Let L be any undecidable language. Define R to be L with all strings of length 1 added to it (if not already part of L). R contains all strings of length 1 over the alphabet, by definition. Also, since L is undecidable, so must be R (the union of an undecidable language and a finite language is also undecidable; see comments and below). But R* contains all strings over the alphabet, a decidable language (indeed, it's regular). To be clear, we just showed how from any undecidable language to construct another one which is a counterexample for the claim.

To see that the union of an undecidable language and a finite language must be undecidable, assume L union R is decidable where L is undecidable and R is a finite. That is, there is a TM that decides membership in L union R. We know there is a TM that decides the L intersect R, since if R is finite then the intersection of it with anything else is too. But L = ((L union R) setminus R) union (L intersect R):

1. L union R is everything in L or R
2. setminus R is everything in L that's not in R
3. union (L intersect R) is everything in L

Since decidable languages are closed under set difference and union, this means L must be decidable, a contradiction. So L union R cannot be decidable for undecidable L and finite R.

Comment: One remark: while "decidability is closed under union" is true, here you really need the fact that undecidability is closed, and this is not the case. However, here R is a finite set, and adding or removing a finite number of elements will never change the (un-)decidability.

Comment: @PeterLeupold You're right, I will amend this to make the correct observation.